# Both incoming and outgoing packets is delayed even though i target incoming only with tc command

Tags: linux-networking, traffic-shaping, tc, network-traffic

I want to deay incoming packets from a particular ip with tc command. I tried

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: prio
sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:3 handle 10: netem delay 500ms
sudo tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dst 10.20.30.400 flowid 1:3
```

This weirdly adds delay to both incoming and outgoing request eventhought it should technically add delay to outgoing (In tc filter i mentioned dst address not src).
Then, for adding delay to only incoming packets i tried changing dst to src like this

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev wlp0s20f3 root handle 1: prio
sudo tc qdisc add dev wlp0s20f3 parent 1:3 handle 10: netem delay 500ms
sudo tc filter add dev wlp0s20f3 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip src 10.20.30.400 flowid 1:3
```

But after this no changing is happened and all the packets incoming and outgoing normally.What i am doing wrong here?

Ref link - [Reference](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.qdisc.filters.html)

To check for delay i have used ping command.

Answer (score 1):

With TC you are only dealing with outgoing packets. To match ongoing ones you need to setup an [ifb](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/ifb).

Also, your connections are chatting, for example if you send a message over TCP, the responder has to acknowledge it received it. So adding delay to one way will add delay to both.

For ping it mesures both ways too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use tc together with ingress and ifb
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dogbunny/fda68f21784025876c57a4dfc3fb6bcc/raw/bfb19da28152364340f2d3f7ef179ee5371fd447/TC_ingress_port_filtering.txt

```
# This a solution for inducing latency on ingress traffic to a specific port
# note: ianae, but many hours of sleuthing and experimenting got me to this answer
# Adapted from https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Traffic_shaping
# Note technically TC can only induce latency on egress traffic so we add an intermediate device which allows
#  us to first identify the traffic we want to affect and then send it to a queue to do <stuff>
# eth0 is the external interface receiving the traffic we want to filter, 4222 is the port we want to add latency to.
# Those are the only values that you should need to change, if necessary.

# Add a TC ingress queue to your external interface, by default you shouldn't have one
sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 handle ffff: ingress
# make sure ifb module is loaded and bring up the interface (IFB = Intermediate Functional Block device)
sudo modprobe ifb
sudo ifconfig ifb0 up
# redirect all traffic to the ifb so that we can later filter on the traffic that leaves that interface
sudo tc filter add dev eth0 parent ffff: protocol all u32 match u32 0 0 action mirred egress redirect dev ifb0
# build up our egress queues and filters
# we need a root, this one uses priority queues which defaults to not modifying any traffic
sudo tc qdisc add dev ifb0 root handle 1: prio
# add a special queue that induces latency
sudo tc qdisc add dev ifb0 parent 1:1 handle 2: netem delay 100ms 50ms distribution normal
# if we find a packet that matches our destination port, send it to the above queue
sudo tc filter add dev ifb0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dport 4222 0xffff flowid 2:1
```